# Does the execution time of the query restore include the wait time? Or not?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL Database.
In the Regressed Queries section of the Azure SQL Database query store, there are Duration and Wait Time.
I thought that Duration includes Wait Time.
However, in some of the query stores I have seen, the Total Wait Time is larger than the Total Duration.
Does Duration not include Wait Time?

Answer (score 0):

No, the duration time in Query Store regression queries section doesn't include wait time. Wait time has been calculated separately.

> Duration time is the time (in ms) for which query was in execution.
>
> Wait time is the time query was in waiting state when resources reach
> limits.

Both these regression criteria in query store measured separately to monitor the performance. The wait time has multiple categories like parallelism, CPU, Network IO as shown in below image.

[image]

Please find some useful articles: [Use the Regressed Queries feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver15#Regressed), [Wait Statistics and Query Store](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/11/waits-2/wait-statistics-query-store)